# Trying to integrate a Vue component into my React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

Attempting to call a Vue component into my React application, and have run into many errors.
I've tried to use `'VueWrapper' from 'vuera`, and I've tried to point the imported `.vue` app right into the filepath, but nothing is making sense.

I eventually tried placing the `.Vue` file into the `src` files of my React app (I know it must be dumb, but I'm new to both React and Vue, and have no idea what I'm doing.)

**The Error**: `Module not found: Can't resolve 'vue' in 'C:\Users\me\WebstormProjects\navtaskv2\node_modules\vuera\dist'`

Here is the plugin `js` file I'm trying to pull the Vue app into:

```
import navtaskv from "./VueApp.vue";
import { VueWrapper } from 'vuera'
import React from "react";


export default () => (
    <div>
        <VueWrapper
            component={navtaskv}
            message='Hello from Vue!'
        />
    </div>
)
```

Not sure if I need to have anything imported on the Vue component's side, but I'm assuming not.
Please be easy on me, I'm truly lost! ):

Comment: error sounds pretty clear: you don't have `vue` installed, so even when `navtaskv2\node_modules\vuera\dist` tries to load it in, it fails. Is it a peer dependency that you forgot to install yourself?

Comment: Well that definitely seems weird, but hey, experimentation is a nice way to get started, so good job, keep it up! Can you confirm that you have installed Vue in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you haven't installed `vue` yet.

Try running `npm install vue` and you should be good to go.